# Vercel doesn't detect repository from Gitlab (University Gitlab)

Tags: django, git, deployment, gitlab, vercel

My university has its own gitlab domain (gitlab.xyz.ac.id) and I want to deploy my university project (a django project) in my university gitlab repository, but when I tried to import gitlab repository in Vercel it didn't detect any repositories that was created in my university gitlab and it just detect the repositories that I've created in my gitlab.com (Note: Both my gitlab.com and university gitlab have the same username)

I tried the import third party git repositories option in Vercel too but it still didn't workout and it still didn't detect my uni project repository from my university Gitlab.

I've already tried deploying one of my django project from my own repository in gitlab.com with CI/CD and it works fine. But for this case, I need to deploy the project that is located in a repository from my university Gitlab.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried contacting Vercel support?

Comment: I've contacted Vercel Support but still haven't received any response until now

Comment: Is your repository public?